# How to make atomic group work with alternations in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have seen simple demo of atomic group. The regex :

```
a(?>bc|b)d
```

I try to run it on java 7 and it doesn't work as expected because it matches in this demo:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a(?>bc|b)d");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abd");
        System.out.println("matches="+matcher.matches());
```

Prints:

```
matches=true
```

But atomic group is to avoid trying all alternatives.

How to turn on atomic group in java?

Comment: Why do you think that atomic group will prevent alternation work? Can you post some link to article that claims it should work this way? Maybe you wanted `a(?>bc|b)c` and test it on `abc`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html.

Comment: there is no `bc` in the string `abd` so the atomic group will never stop at `bc`, but will continue to `b` and the overall match happens as expected, no backtracking is involved. and regular-expression.info contains completely different demo from what you are writing, regex `a(?>bc|b)c` will not match string `abc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood example from http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

You need to understand that purpose of atomic group is to prevent backtracking so it is impossible to change **already matched** substring with new substring. But match will not be found for first case of alternation then it is OK to test next case of alternation.

So for string `abd` and regex `a(?>bc|b)c`

```
regex parts    |  matched String parts
---------------+----------------------
a              |  a 
(?>bc|b)       |  b - it happens because `bc` can't be matched so next case 
               |      from alternation inside atomic group is used
d              |  d
```

In case of regex from linked article `a(?>bc|b)c` and String `abc` you will get

```
regex parts    |  matched String parts
---------------+----------------------
a              |  a 
(?>bc|b)       |  bc <--------+ 
c              |  nothing - c was already matched and "possessed" by atomic 
               |            group so `c` can't be used here
```

and because `c`

```
a(?>bc|b)c
         ^
```

couldn't be matched you will see `false` as result of `"abc".matches("a(?>bc|b)c")`